# Is it safe to use const external value as non-const extern value?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, constants, extern

Please see next codes and result:

foo.c:

```
const int extern_const = 1;
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int extern_const;

int main(void)
{
    printf("before: %d\n", extern_const);
    extern_const = 2;
    printf("after : %d\n", extern_const);
    return 0;
}
```

compile and result:

```
$ gcc -shared -fpic foo.c -o libfoo.so
$ gcc main.c -L. -lfoo  -o test
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./test
before: 1
after : 2
```

I declared a const int variable `extern_const` and it resides in a shared library `libfoo.so`.
In main.c, I declared the extern_const as just `extern int` not `extern const int` and changed the value from 1 to 2. **Is this safe and effective?**

The execution result shows that the substitution works anyway. I've heard that overwriting const value caucses undefined behavior and in fact, when I compiled foo.c and main.c at once (without creating shared library), the program actually ended with segmentation fault before the second printf.

What I want to know is next things:

1. Is it safe to change the value of any const variable in **external library**, generally?
2. If not, is it safe for GCC/GNU toolkits?
3. If both of 1. and 2. are wrong, did I get a lucky case of undefined behaviors?
4. If 1. or 2. is right, what does make such difference for the cases with/without library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are absolutely correct about this being Undefined Behavior and thus something you should not do. The reason your broken code is "working" for you is a side effect of the way dynamic linking works, namely *copy relocations*. Basically, what happens is that, since the main executable is not position-independent, it has to have addresses for all data objects it accesses directly hard-coded as immediates in the instructions which perform the accesses. Thus, the linker allocates writable space (since the value, which comes from a shared library at runtime, can't be known) in the main program's writable data segment and includes an instruction to the dynamic linker for it to copy the value from the shared library to the main program's data when performing relocations at startup. Any references from the shared library are then patched up to point to the new copy in the main program's data.

If you want to see your code fail, try to compile your main program as a position-independent executable:

```
$ gcc -fPIE -pie main.c -L. -lfoo  -o test
```

and see what happens. Note that PIE is default on many hardened systems. Likewise, the ABIs for some cpu architectures (MIPS is one, if I'm not mistaken) never need copy relocations, and thus your program should crash even without PIE on such archs.

Comment: BTW keep in mind that, since the object is still formally *const*, the compiler may already have performed constant folding/propagation using it when building the library. Thus, even when the copy relocation "allows" you to make changes to the object, the library it was defined in may not actually see your changes. The value may already be an immediate in the library's machine code.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying constant objects is **Undefined Behavior**. Anything may happen.

In your case, you might have become **unlucky** because GCC does not yet pool all constant variables and literals, it did not put it into a read-only section (Define more of them and it might happen), and your `main()` is the first and last code accessing that external constant object (though under false flag as non-const).

> #### 6.7.3 Type qualifiers §6
>
> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is
>   made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>   with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.133)

Answer (score 3):

1. No.
2. No.
3. Yes.

Basically, it's up to the compiler/toolchain/operating system to provide protection for const variables. Some combinations of those go out of their way to make sure that what's supposed to be read-only will be read-only even if it means allocating a whole page (several kB) just to store one variable. Others make different trade-offs and will not waste a lot of space just to protect one variable and trust the programmer to not do crazy things like this.

Answer (score 0):

In foo.c, add:

```
int y;
void f(void) {
  y = extern_const;
}
```

Compile foo.c with optimization to assembly. Read the assembly for `f()`. If your compiler is like mine, you should see that `f()` has been optimized to the equivalent of `y = 1;`

This means that according to my compiler (and probably yours), what you did is not okay, and you deserve any strange demon that may fly out of your nose as a result of declaring `extern_const` differently in different files.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is violating the one definition rule. This is undefined behavior, so *anything* can happen during compile phase and your program is not guaranteed to do anything useful, see also [here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213).

From [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> #### J.2 Undefined behavior
>
> Two declarations of the same object or function specify types that are not compatible
>   (6.2.7).

also

> #### 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> 2 All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

also

> #### 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> 10 For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version
>   of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers
>   does not affect the specified type.

Besides, as others stated, it is also undefined behavior to modify a const object:

> #### 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> 6 If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is
>   made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>   with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.133)